# ASP.NET Core - "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found" Error

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, token, bearer-token

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project where I'm trying to implement JWT authentication and authorisation. However, I keep running into the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.`

Here's the relevant part of my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SecretKey"))
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

And the Controller i'm using for testing:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok("Pong");
    }
}
```

I'm testing the using Postman and I've included the JWT token, that i've generated, in the Authorization header as a Bearer token.

[image: postman screenshot]

I'm expecting for the programm to say "pong"

I've tried the following:

- Checked the order of middleware - it seems to be correct.
- Checked that the [Authorize] attribute is present in the controller.

Despite all this, I'm still facing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Code looks fine, try clean and rebuild solution.

Comment: I have a test in my side with your code and I didn't meet any issue, everything worked well. And we could see that it's an 500 error which pointing to the `builder.Services.AddAuthentication`, so you might rebuild your project like Dimitris said, or use `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(option => {xxxx})`